# Pass array in CURL along with fields in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to pass an array along with the fields in CURL
Here what I exactly want to do,

```
$url = Configurations::DOMAIN . '/register';
$fields = "username=software3@gmail.com&password=test123&hobbies=array('cricket','football')";

    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if (!is_null($fields)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, Configurations::USER_AGENT);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        //Set Cookie
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    }
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I want something like,

```
["hobbies"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "cricket",
  [1]=>
  string(1) "football"
}
```

But getting,

```
["hobbies"]=>
string(10) "array('cricket','football')"
```

What is the correct way to write $fields?

Comment: Could you tries to pass &hobbies[]=cricket&hobbies[]=football like this.

Comment: yes, but not getting desired output.

Comment: Okay, got the proper output. Thanks.

Comment: could you post how you get the output ?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh &hobbies[]=cricket&hobbies[]=football I forgot to put array symbol "[]". Thanks again.

Comment: mine pleasure. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some search, the solution is to use,

```
..&hobbies[]=cricket&hobbis[]=football..
```

This is the proper way.